# $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}n\log\left(1+\bigg[\frac {f(x)} n \bigg]^\alpha\right)\ dx$ where $f$ is an integrable function

Tags: integration, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann-integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f(x) \geq 0 \ \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \  \text{ and } \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f > 0 .$$
Calculate, based on the value of $\alpha$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}n\log\left(1+\bigg[\frac {f(x)} n \bigg]^\alpha\right)\ dx,$$
where $\alpha \in (0, +\infty)$.
I have to use the Lebesgue measure, and the monotone convergence theorem, but I can't figure how to based on the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Hint: Extending the function $g(x,n) = n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f(x)}{n}\right)^\alpha\right)$ to allow positive real $n$, not just integer $n$, will help both to show $g(x,n)$ is increasing in $n$ at each fixed $x$ and to find $\lim_{n \to +\infty} g(x,n)$.

Comment: How can you show that $g(x, n)$ is increasing in $n$ for every value of $\alpha$?